# Fixed points of $u'= u(1-u+ \alpha v)$, $v' = \rho v(1-v + \beta u)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, biology

Hopefully a simple question however it has me stumped...

I have the following system:

$\frac{dN_1}{dt} = r_1N_1(1- \frac{N_1}{k_1} + b_{12} \frac{N_2}{k_1})$

$\frac{dN_2}{dt} = r_2N_2(1- \frac{N_2}{k_2} + b_{21} \frac{N_1}{k_2})$

Transforming it to its dimensionless form (skipped workings since not relevant to question):

$\frac{du}{d \tau} = u(1-u+ \alpha v)$

$\frac{dv}{d \tau} = \rho v(1-v + \beta u)$

Setting both equal 0 we get the following steady states:

$(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ and $(1+ \alpha v, 1+ \beta u)$

**QUESTION:**

How was the steady state

$(1+ \alpha v, 1+ \beta u)$

transformed into

$(\frac{1+ \alpha}{1-\alpha \beta}, \frac{1+ \beta}{1-\alpha \beta})$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that it is absurd to declare that $(1+ \alpha v, 1+ \beta u)$ is a fixed point since one would need to know $(u,v)$ to know the point. Rather, you are probably trying to solve the system $$u=1+\alpha v\quad v=1+\beta u,$$ whose solution $(u^*,v^*)$ might very well be equal to the point $(\frac{1+ \alpha}{1-\alpha \beta}, \frac{1+ \beta}{1-\alpha \beta})$ in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steady state is when the derivatives are both zero.
This occurs when $u(1-u+\alpha v)=0$ and $\rho v (1-v + \beta u)=0$.
If $u=0$ then we have either $v=0$ or $v=1$ and similarly if $v=0$ we have $u=0$ or $u=1$.  That accounts for your first three cases.

The final case is the equations $1-u+\alpha v=0$ and $1-v + \beta u=0$ (which is equivalent to your fourth solution).  Just solve these two simultaneous equations and you get the solution you mentioned.  That is, just substitute $u=1 +\alpha v$ into the equation $1-v + \beta u=0$ to solve for $v$ and then substitute the value or $v$ back into the first equation to find $u$.